# maven plugin to be used for building an osgi bundle containing camel-routes and some POJO's for deploying inside fuse-servicemix 4.3.0?

Tags: osgi, maven-plugin, bundle, apache-camel

**Which maven plugin is used for building an osgi bundle containing camel-routes and some POJO's for deploying inside fuse-servicemix 4.3.0 . i have used pax as well as maven-bundle plugin for deploying into fuse servicemix .i get a lotof error's using these .any other good maven-plugin ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some documentation here about the maven archetypes
http://servicemix.apache.org/SMX4/creating-a-bundle-using-maven.html

There is a newer version of the plugin than listed on the web page

The latest release is here
http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/servicemix/tooling/servicemix-camel-osgi-bundle/2010.01/

But keep an eye in the central repo as newer version will be released.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [bundle://33.0:0/META-INF/spring/camel-client.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.f
actory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface

Comment: thanks for the answer but i get the above error on deploying the bundle into apache-servicemix-4.3.0-fuse-00-00..what could be the reason

Comment: Use the SMX mailinglist to get help for such kind or the FuseSource forum